# Factorisation of $p^2 q$

Tags: number-theory

[image: The original question]In an online quiz as part of a number theory module I've been asked how many positive divisors does an integer with a prime factorisation of $p^2 q$ have. Second to this I have been asked what is the smallest non-negative integer in this factorisation. 
I submitted answers of 6 and 1 respectively thinking this was the factorisation:

1. $p^2$
2. $q$
3. $pq$
4. $p$
5. $p^2 q$
6. $1$

I am told that 1 is not the smallest nonnegative integer upon submitting this answer. I am being stupid and missing something or is the question looking for incorrect answers. Sorry for such an easy question.

Comment: I agree with your answer. $1$ is clearly a divisor, and how can there possibly be a smaller (non-negative) one? Who told you that that was wrong?

Comment: Well, 1 is always the smallest positive divisor of any integer number.

Comment: thought as much, the quiz tells me the answer is wrong as soon as I submit it. Thanks alot

Comment: Can you reprint the question exactly as it appears, with no changes?  As it stands, saying "in this factorization" has no obvious meaning.  What factorization?  If they are referring to $p^2q$ then perhaps they mean $p$, as it is customary (though hardly obligatory) to list the primes in ascending order.

Comment: a screenshot of the original question has now been included

Comment: I have edited my answer: your question asked for the smallest positive integer _with_ that factorization, and the answer is $12=2^2\times3$

Comment: To be fair, it would've been a lot easier to interpret correctly had they said "What is the smallest non-negative integer that has such a factorisation?" There are probably other clear formulations as well, but the original one, while correct, was almost borderline ambiguous IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a number $n$ is factorized as $n=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\dots p_k^{r_k}$ then you can create a divisor by combining all the $p_i$ factors, taking them 0, 1, 2, ..., $r_i$ times. So the total number of divisors of $n$ is
$$
(r_1+1)(r_2+1)\dots(r_k+1).
$$

So your factorization is good.

[Edit]

I have seen the original question, which asked for the smallest positive integer *with* this factorization. It is the number obtained by substituting $p=2$ and $q=3$, so the answer is $2^2\times3=12$.

Comment: OK, so my interpretation was wrong. I delete my answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks very much!

Comment: @Peter yes, the question asked for an integer _with_ that factorization

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there are six positive divisors of $p^2q$ for prime $p$ and $q$.

The second part of the question is terribly worded.  The answer depends on what you guess the questionner wanted.  THe smallest number in the factorization is the lesser of $p$ and $p$, but in that case, why did he say "non-negative".  The smallest devisor is $1$, but then why did he say "in this factorization?"